# Issue looping through all of the elements in an Array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, object

I have an Array of objects:

```
let myArray = [
    {myParagraph: "This is paragraph 1"},
    {myParagraph: "This is paragraph 2"},
    {myParagraph: "This is paragraph 3"},
    {myParagraph: "This is paragraph 4"},
    {myParagraph: "This is paragraph 5"},
]
```

I want to loop through and display all of these objects. These objects should be paginated. To do this, I used this code:

```
let page = 1;
let button_number = 1;

let first_element_shown = 0;
let last_element_shown = 10;

let number_of_pages = Math.ceil(myArray.length / 10);

for (let i of myArray) {
    for (let j = 0; j < number_of_pages; j++) {
        for (let k = first_element_shown; k < last_element_shown; k++) {
            let card = document.createElement('div')
            let myParagraph = document.createElement('p');
            myParagraph.innerText = i.myParagraph;
            card.appendChild('myParagraph')
            document.getElementById("example_DIV").appendChild(card);
           }
    }
}
```

However, this loops through and displays the same objects multiple times. Is there a way to loop through all of the objects in myArray without using the `for (let i of myArray)` line in order to stop the same objects from showing multiple times.

Comment: `card.appendChild('myParagraph')` this parameter `'myParagraph'` that you are sending here is not a node element, it's just a string so your `appendChild` function will throw an error. You have to send your `myParagraph` element in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set

1. `pageSize`
2. `page`
3. `start` equal to `(page - 1) * pageSize`
4. `end` equal to `start + pageSize`
5. use `slice` method to slice the shown part in the array.

This is an example.

```js
let myArray = [{
    myParagraph: "This is paragraph 1"
  },
  {
    myParagraph: "This is paragraph 2"
  },
  {
    myParagraph: "This is paragraph 3"
  },
  {
    myParagraph: "This is paragraph 4"
  },
  {
    myParagraph: "This is paragraph 5"
  },
  {
    myParagraph: "This is paragraph 6"
  },
  {
    myParagraph: "This is paragraph 7"
  },
  {
    myParagraph: "This is paragraph 8"
  },
  {
    myParagraph: "This is paragraph 9"
  },
  {
    myParagraph: "This is paragraph 10"
  },
  {
    myParagraph: "This is paragraph 11"
  },
  {
    myParagraph: "This is paragraph 12"
  },
  {
    myParagraph: "This is paragraph 13"
  },
  {
    myParagraph: "This is paragraph 14"
  },
]

let pageSize = 3;
let page = 1;
const elementsContainer = document.querySelector('.elements-container');
const next = document.querySelector('#next');
const prev = document.querySelector('#prev');


const changePageNumber = (pageValue) => {
  console.log(pageValue)
  let page = pageValue;
  let start = (page - 1) * pageSize;
  let end = start + pageSize;
  let shownElements = myArray.slice(start, end);

  elementsContainer.innerHTML = '';

  shownElements.forEach(item => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.textContent = item.myParagraph;
    elementsContainer.append(div);
  })
}

next.addEventListener('click', () => changePageNumber(++page));
prev.addEventListener('click', () => changePageNumber(--page));
changePageNumber(page)
```

```css
.elements-container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<button id="next">Next</button>
<button id="prev">Previous</button>

<div class="elements-container">
</div>
```

Comment: The user should not be able to go to any page before the first page or any page after the first page

Answer (score 0):

```
let page = 1;
let button_number = 1;
let count = 0;
let first_element_shown = 0;
let last_element_shown = 10;

let number_of_pages = Math.ceil(myArray.length / 10);

    for (let j = 0; j < number_of_pages; j++) {
        for (let k = first_element_shown; k < last_element_shown & count<myArray.length; k++) {
            let card = document.createElement('div')
            let myParagraph = document.createElement('p');
            myParagraph.innerText = myArray[count].myParagraph;
            card.appendChild(myParagraph)
            document.getElementById("example_DIV").appendChild(card);
            count++
           }
    }
```

While this isn't perfect, it fixes some of your issues and you can probably figure out the rest from there.